# Existence of Sequence and Measure for every subset of the natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

The following is from Axler's Measure Theory text.

Denote S to be the sigma algebra of all sets of natural numbers. Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on $\left({Z}^{+}, S\right) .$ Prove that there is a sequence $v_{1}, v_{2}, \ldots$ in $[0, \infty]$ such that
$$
\mu(B)=\sum_{i \in B} v_{i}
$$
for every set $B\subset Z^+$

*I am unsure how to interpret such a measure. It is only briefly mentioned as an example in the text:
Suppose $X$ is a set, $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$ -algebra on $X,$ and $w: X \rightarrow[0, \infty]$ is a function. Define a measure $\mu$ on $(X, \mathcal{S})$ by
$$
\mu(E)=\sum_{x \in E} w(x)
$$
for $E \in \mathcal{S} .$ [Here the sum is defined as the supremum of all finite subsums $\sum_{x \in D} w(x)$ as $D$ ranges over all finite subsets of $\left.E .\right]$*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $v_i$ as $\mu(\{i\})$. Then $\mu (B)=\mu (\bigcup_{i \in B}(\{i\})=\sum_{i \in B} \mu(\{i\})=\sum_{i \in B} v_i$ by countable additivity.

Comment: This may be a bad question, but is $i \in B$ simply a natural number? So basically $\mu(\{i\})$ is the measure of the element (/natural number)?

Comment: Yes. $B$ is a subset of $Z^+$, so all of its elements are positive integers, i.e. natural numbers. It might be new (and thus a bit strange) to see $B$ showing up as both a measurable set and indexing a summation, but it's completely valid.